# Find a basis of $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V = \mathbb P_4$ and $W = \{p(x) ∈ V : p(1) = p'(1) = 0\}$.
>
> 1. Assume that $W$ is a subspace of $V$. Find a basis of $W$ and thereby
>      determine the dimension of $W$.

I'm not sure how to find the basis. I know that the equation $p(x)$ has to have at least $(x-1)^2$ in it, but I don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: The space $\mathbb{P}_{4}$ denotes polynomials of degree less or equal to 4 with real coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general polynomial in one variable with real coefficients of degree 4 has the form
$$
p(x) = a_{4}x^{4} + a_{3}x^{3} + a_{2}x^{2} + a_{1}x + a_{0}.
$$
Thus it has 5 unknowns and the space $V$ has dimension 5 (a basis is given, for example, by the monomials $\{ x^{n} ~|~n=0,\ldots,4 \}$. If you now have two conditions, such as $p(1) = 0, p'(1) = 0$, this should suffice to determine 2 of the coefficients and so the polynomials in $W$ should have just 3 free coefficients. So you can expect $W$ to be 3 dimensional.

This is, of course, not a formal proof. So let us translate your conditions into equations for the coefficients:

1. We want to have $p(1) = 0$ which yields 
   $$
   a_{4} + a_{3} + a_{2} + a_{1} + a_{0} = 0.
   $$
2. We would also like to have $p'(1) = 0$ which translates into
   $$
   4 a_{4} + 3 a_{3} + 2 a_{2} + a_{1} = 0.
   $$

The first equation can be solved for $a_{0}$, say, to give
$$
a_{0} = - (a_{4} + a_{3} + a_{2} + a_{1})
$$
and the second equation can be solved for $a_{1}$, say, to give
$$
a_{1} = - (4a_{4} + 3a_{3} + 2a_{2} ).
$$
This can be substituted in the previous equation to get rid of the $a_{1}$ term and you will be left with a form of the polynomial that only depends on 3 coefficients: $a_{4}, a_{3}$ and $a_{2}$. Then, rewriting your general polynomial $p$ using this information, you see that the space has to be 3 dimensional.

Hope that helps!

Andre

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now!!! Thank you very much!